# How to translate ActiveModel attribute values in Rails 6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a status table with 10 different statuses.  The columns are id and name.

When I display the "name" attribute in the view (especially as a nested attribute), I can't seem to figure out how to translate the value.

For example:

```
<%= t'@tank.status.name' %>
```

I tried adding the following to my fr.yml file

```
new: "Nouveau"
activerecord:
    models:
      status:
        one: 'Statut'
        other: 'Statuts'
        attributes:
          name:
            new: 'Nouveau'
```

but it didn't seem to access either of these entries.

How can I translate nested attribute values?

**Edit**

This sloppy way works, but it seems...just wrong.

```
class Status < ApplicationRecord
def name
  case id
  when 1
    I18n.t('new')
  when 2
    ..
  end
end
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?  That code makes me want to take a shower.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation is important in YML file, you could try this:

```yaml
activerecord:
    models:
      status:
        one: 'Statut'
        other: 'Statuts'
    attributes:
      status/name:
        new: 'Nouveau'
```

Then `Status.human_attribute_name('name.new')` will reutrn 'Nouveau'.

Check out details on Rails Guides - [Translations for Active Record Models](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

Comment: Do I have to know the value of status.name?  Because when I'm displaying in the view, I don't know what the status will be, it's dynamically modified by the user.

Comment: @JeffO Yes, that's how i18n works. How about creating a few statuses, and then let users choose from those, so you can add those i18n.

Comment: I want to display the state of a record that was set by some previous action.  The user isn't setting the status from a select input.

Comment: Ok, then you need to config i18n to all possible actions, like: new, edit, delete...

Comment: But in the View, how do I access that translated value without knowing what it will be?

Comment: If there is just a few possible actions by users, the you you could add those to `fr.yml` file in advance. If there is infinite actions by user, then may be no way to do this.  It's not about how to translate any more, it's about how to design the system.

Comment: I've added them.  I'm actually confused on the syntax to access them.  Let's say I have 4 statuses: new, processed, finished, sold.  The status of the object is changed by other user actions in the application.  On an index page, I want to display all the records for that object type, all with various statuses.  What is the code to get that translated status when I don't explicitly write the value?

Comment: @JeffO You could just get that by `Status.human_attribute_name("name.#{record.status}")`, `record.status` may need be changed based your code.